# visually resize images when uploaded inline in ckeditor

Tags: wysiwyg, media

is there a way to resize images after uploaded in the inline ckeditor?

if i have a big picture 2000x2000 and upload it (not via IMCE) to the editor, the image is huge and it is displayed in full size.

[image: See full size image]

i have to scroll to left and down and drag the resize button multiple time until i get the result i can work with.

[image: See minimized image]

i miss the settings dialogue from D7 where i can define an image size upon upload. i cannot find any extension and i read many discussions that the D8 ckeditor has a lot less functions than in D7.
i read about the reason is responsive design but when i resize the image via drag there is still height and width added. so whats the point on this?

Comment: _when i resize the image via drag there is still height and width added. so whats the point on this?_ By resizing you're saying you want the image to be a particular size, ckeditor is just honouring that. The CSS which overrides it and makes it 'responsive' is a separate thing. You can't really have it both ways...imagine if your stylesheet didn't have the usual `img { width: 100%; height: auto }` in it, and you'd resized the image via ckeditor. You'd be pretty annoyed if the width/height attributes were missing right?

Comment: @Clive yes ofcourse you are right. but is there a solution for display the images smaller inside the editor then their actual width are? because it is rendered correctly on the finished site (with a 300px width).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a pretty simple solution, but it does feel a bit hack-y.

1. Add a CSS file to a module/theme with contents like

   ```
   img { max-width: 200px; height: auto; }
   ```
2. Implement [`hook_ckeditor_css_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21ckeditor%21ckeditor.api.php/function/hook_ckeditor_css_alter/8.4.x) to get that CSS file loaded in the WYSIWYG iframe:

   ```
   function hook_ckeditor_css_alter(array &$css, Editor $editor) {
     $css[] = drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/css/mymodule-ckeditor.css';
   }
   ```

Once that's up and running images in the WYSIWYG should be constrained in width to whatever you set in the CSS file. You might need to resort to `!important`, depending on what other styles are already active; it'll need some tweaking no doubt.

Comment: works fine with custom module and ckeditor hook. thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

If your html contains a style attribute e.g.it will block the resizing of an image.

```
<img src="image.jpg" style="width:300px;height:200px;" />
```

Remove the style attribute to make sure resizing works. Searched a very long time for this!